# How to validate Object Prop with PropType

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have the following `props` code:

```
  props: {
    ponyModel: {
      type: Object as PropType<PonyModel>,
      validator: pony => pony.speed > 5
    }
  },
```

PonyModel interface:

```
export interface PonyModel {
        id?: number;
        name: string;
        color: string;
        speed: number;
}
```

Compiling fails with the following message:

```
Failed to compile.

    src/components/Pony.vue:21:26
    TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.
        19 |     ponyModel: {
        20 |       type: Object as PropType<PonyModel>,
      > 21 |       validator: pony => pony.speed > 5
           |                          ^^^^
        22 |     }
        23 |   },
```

If I remove the `validator` part, the code works.

I have tried to indicate the type, but failed to do so:

```
src/components/Pony.vue:21:43

    TS2339: Property 'speed' does not exist on type 'PonyModel'.
        19 |     ponyModel: {
        20 |       type: Object as PropType<PonyModel>,
      > 21 |       validator: (pony:PonyModel) => pony.speed > 5
           |                                           ^^^^^
        22 |     }
        23 |   },
```

I failed to find info about proper validation in this case in the documentation with PropType usage. What is missing here?

**update** I have created a stackblitz example of the problem, and for my big suprise, it works. https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-2tkemh?file=src/components/Pony.vue
So I am not entirely sure, what causes the problem in my main application, but this is probably not related to the copied code sections :\

Comment: You might want to add the [tag:typescript] tag.

Comment: Under the hood the [type](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/util/props.js#L169) parameter is already using `instanceof type` so you just need `type: PonyModel`

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in a newly generated Vue-CLI project (w/TypeScript), using the second snippet in question that has the type annotation. What's your environment? Do you have a repro link (to GitHub)?

Comment: ([screenshot](https://imgur.com/I91OPm6))

Comment: @Ohgodwhy if I do that, the code wont compile: `Object is of type 'unknown'.` and TSLint gives error: TS2693: 'PonyModel' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Comment: @tony19 I have recreated the app in stackblitz, and it seems to be working now. https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-2tkemh?file=src/components/Pony.vue 
Probably I have messed up some other setting in the project - sorry for the miguidance! I am just learning Vue.js.